# Tried everything to get index.php out of the URL and everything returns Not Found error

Tags: url, seo, .htaccess

Things I've confirmed:

Site is on Ubuntu 13.10 server at `/var/www/mysite.com/htdocs/`

1. Uncommented: `/var/www/mysite.com/htdocs/.htaccess`

   `RewriteBase /`
2. Catalog URL Key = phones
3. Desired URL for this category = `http://mysite.com/phones.html`
4. Added the following in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`:

   `<VirtualHost *:80>
   ...
   <Directory /var/www/>
       AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>`
5. Restarted apache
6. Cleared Magento Cache
7. Cleared Magento Indexing
8. System -> Configuration -> Web -> Use Web Server Rewrites = Yes
9. System -> Configuration -> Web -> Secure -> Use Secure URLs in Frontend = Yes

Tried adding the `AllowOverride All` directory code to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.com.conf` as well and the result is the same. I've tried `<Directory /var/www/mysite.com/htdocs/>` and `<Directory /var/www/mysite.com/>` along with the version I put above. No dice.

The only thing the options above does is remove index.php from the links paths and breaks all the links. Trying to use url `http://mysite.com/index.php/phones.html` still works, but has been removed from all links.

Comment: The same issue for me. I have no idea where to continue. Maybe when Magento tried to modify `.htaccess`, it wasn't writable? That makes no sense, since whatever I do in the file, it makes no difference.

Comment: Do you have a rewrite rule in your .htaccess file, like `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that the Rewrite Mod is on inside of Apache?

Try this:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite

sudo service apache restart
```